# C - how to print only filled rows in 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, printing, printf

I have 2D array in size of [temp][26] filled with the char '#' or nothing.
some rows are empty, some rows filled with that char.
how I print **only** the rows that are filled.

this is my start.

```
for (i=0;i<(temp);i++){
    for (j=0;j<26;j++)
        printf("%c",graph[temp][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: If you want to print full array, you should use `printf("%c", graph[i][j]);`, also use `if` (as it is mentioned in answer) if you want to print only one with '#'.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a 'if' condition ... I don't see your problem

```
for (i=0;i<(temp);i++){
    for (j=0;j<26;j++)
        if(graph[temp][j] == '#') printf("%c",graph[temp][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant you want to print only the rows filled with '#' and all of them:

```
for (i=0;i<(temp);i++)
    if(graph[temp][0] == '#') //check only first character will be enough
        printf("%s\n",graph[temp]); //print all current line
printf("\n");
```